# What do you call an emotional, sensitive person's character?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-meaning, word-request

Is there any fixed term which can describe an emotional person who is very gentle, kind, sensitive, and can be easily upset?

I think a construction of "gentle," "delicate," and "tender" plus "morale" or possible "character" can work; although, this is only a simple guess and rooted from the quality that we use in our language; i.e.

> - He has a tender morale/character.
> - He has a gentle morale/character.
> - He has a delicate morale/character.

Please let me know how would you refer to such an individual.

**Added:**

In order to avoid any further misunderstanding, I guess I have to explain a little more! As you see in Cambridge Dictionary, the adjective **"delicate"** means: **needing careful treatment, especially because easily damaged**. Also, the word **"tender"** has a very close meaning where it explains it as: **easily hurt**; therefore, I think I can say: **he has a "delicate character"** OR **he has a "tender character"** in a figurative way; but the question is that do these sentences make sense when they stand alone or they require to be in a context to be understood or they are kind of confusing statements and sound odd and unnatural?

Comment: "Morale" means the *confidence, enthusiasm, and discipline* of a person or group *at a particular time*.  I don't think you are using this word properly. An emotional person's morale would go up and down, depending on how they were feeling. Your question is like asking "What is a sensitive person's  hair length?"  There can be no single answer.  "Morale" is completely different to "character".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a writing advice sort of question.

Comment: @JimReynolds, the question is just fine - it's about word usage.

Answer (score 1):

*Sensitive* or *scrupulous character* can all be used.

Most of suggestions from your question also go with *character,* but not really with morale or spirits.

"Character" is something you can *describe* and you can use almost unlimited number of words to do so.

"Morale" and "spirit" are something you *judge,* and the words like sensitive or gentle do not work here.

You need to take care to avoid phrases that have other known meanings and check them in a search engine. For example, ["tender character"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tender%20character%22&newwindow=1&ei=VTTRXNLGCcjPwAK69a3QDw&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiSxaGm84jiAhXIJ1AKHbp6C_o4ChDy0wMIbA&biw=1280&bih=918) (using quotes) can refer to "legal tender character of notes," which is a legal term.